# How to use static folder via express on shared hosting

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am trying to use a static folder in a simple Node.js+Express application, but always end up with a 404 error.

I created a basic structure via `express project_name` with the following folder structure (I reduced it to the necessary parts):

```
app.js
/views
 \-- layout.pug
/public
 \-- /stylesheets
      \-- style.css
```

`app.js` was created by Express an it looks like this (also reduced):

```js
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');

var routes = require('./routes/index');
var users = require('./routes/users');

var app = express();

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'pug');

app.use('/', routes);
app.use('/users', users);

module.exports = app;
```

I reference a stylesheet `style.css` in `layout.pug` like this

```
link(rel='stylesheet', href='stylesheets/style.css')
```

I might want to add, that I am hosting my application on a shared host ([Uberspace)](http://uberspace.de). This means my project is located in my user's home directory, the application is run as a service (daemon) and I redirect it via `.htaccess` from my user's `html/project_name-folder` to `http://localhost:port` (Node.js-application).

When I run the application, I always get a 404 error on `http://domain.tld/project_name/stylesheets/style.css`

**Edit**

This is my `.htaccess` (I replaced the actual port number with 'port'):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteCond %{ENV:HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule .* https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
RewriteRule (.*) http://localhost:port/$1 [P]
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:
`app.use('/' + project_name, express.static(path.join(__dirname, project_name)));`

Comment: I tried that, but unfortunately, it didn't work. I get a 502, 'Service temporarily unavailabe'.